# Need to fetch all order details according to product name and SKU and all checkout fields

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

```
select
p.order_id,
p.order_item_id,
p.order_item_name,
p.order_item_type,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_product_id' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as productID,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_qty' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Qty,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_variation_id' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as variationID,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_line_total' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as lineTotal,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_line_subtotal_tax' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as subTotalTax,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_line_tax' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Tax,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_tax_class' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as taxClass,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_line_subtotal' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as subtotal
from
wp_woocommerce_order_items as p,
wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as pm
 where order_item_type = 'line_item' and
 p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id
 group by
p.order_item_id
```

This query is working for fetching all orders according to product names and now i want to add sku and other checkout fields

Comment: JOIN's exist since 30  years now, i think you shpuld also use them freely, besides whar pevents you to add more row to extract the information, if they are present in both tables you can select them

Comment: could you please help me with the code i do that but it not working for me

Comment: as i don't have woocommerce, i can't tell where the information you need is comming from, but here you find multiple, besides if you have phpmyadmin you can run the code. also also if you have an error in in your new code, post this as well